# Need to append forward slash but only when href doesn't have a .aspx in the value

Tags: jquery

This is what i have so far and it works fine:

```
$("a[id=terminalNode]").each(function() {
    var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(this).attr("href", _href + '/');
});
```

However, there are some instances where the value could have a ".aspx" in the href. Is there an easy way to filter these out of my each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.indexOf()` to check if a string contains a specific string. It is case-sensitive so `.toLowerCase()` might be a good idea:

```
$("a[id=terminalNode]").each(function () {
    var _href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (_href.toLowerCase().indexOf(".aspx") == -1) {
        $(this).attr("href", _href + "/");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a[id=terminalNode]").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.toLowerCase().slice(-5) != '.aspx')
        $(this).attr("href", href + '/');
});
```

or

```
$("a[id=terminalNode]").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.toLowerCase().test('.aspx'))
        $(this).attr("href", href + '/');
});
```

or

```
$("a[id=terminalNode]").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf('.aspx') != -1)
        $(this).attr("href", href + '/');
});
```

however why would you have a foreach on a[id=terminalNode]? Something with an id should only appear once on the page.